# Android gradle plugin: Could not find method additionalParameters() on DexOptions

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

To add parameters to "dx":

```
dexOptions {
    incremental false
    javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    additionalParameters "--multi-dex", "--set-max-idx-number", "48000"
}
```

error like following:

```
Error:(39, 0) Could not find method additionalParameters() for arguments [--multi-dex, --set-max-idx-number, 48000] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions.
```

As [DexOptions api doc](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions.html) says, additionalParameters is it's property.

Other info:

compileSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

Gradle plugin 2.2.0

Gradle 2.14.1

Studio 2.2

Answer (score 0):

`additionalParameters` is a list of of additional parameters to be passed to dx.

```
android {
  dexOptions {
    additionalParameters += '--minimal-main-dex'
    //additionalParameters += '--main-dex list=$projectDir/<filename>'.toString()'
    //additionalParameters += '--set-max-idx-number=55000'
  }
}
```

https://github.com/casidiablo/multidex

Comment: "moreOptions" defined outside dexOptions. still got error: "Error:(41, 0) Could not find method additionalParameters() for arguments [[--multi-dex, --set-max-idx-number, 48000]] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions"

Comment: "Could not get unknown property 'additionalParameters' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions."

Comment: Changed single to double quotes for strings. Not sure if that will fix the issue though.

Comment: Your initial problem is fixed. I'm just unsure why you are getting this new issue. Hopefully someone else can jump in on this.